# Access Guest Ubuntu's Folder from Host Mac OS X?

Tags: virtualbox, 14.04, macosx, shared-folders

Is it possible to access the folders inside my guest Ubuntu 14.04 from my host Mac OS X? I've found some articles stating that it's possible to do this kind of "reverse-sharing" for Windows host using Samba, but can't seem to find the instructions for Mac OS X host.

Comment: Use host-only networking and openssh-server on the guest, then mount on MacOS?

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to do it through Samba.

In your Ubuntu 14.04 host, right-click in the folder you want to share, go to Properties and then in "Local network shared resource" tab (or something like that, I have a Spanish installation), click all the checkboxes. Then, press "Create share" button and then Close. Install all packages that your Ubuntu asks for.

Later in your Mac OS host, go to Finder --> Go --> Connect to server. Provide next details:

- Server: smb://your_host_local_network_ip_address
- Access as guest.

You'll be able to see Ubuntu shared folder.